# Firestore onWrite callback in Node.js has undefined context

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've setup a simple `onWrite` listener on documents in my `sandbox` collection, just to test the listener API and see that I know how to use it.

Apparently I don't, because the following `index.js` in my `functions` dir:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sandbox = functions.firestore.document('sandbox/{wildcard}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        console.log("In")
        console.log("Before is " + change.before)
        console.log("Wildcard is " + context.params.wildcard)
        return null
    })
```

results in the following output (whenever I add / remove a field in my `sandbox/yoohoo` document):

```
In
Before is undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you update the firebase-function to v1? You can check the in package.json or try the old way `onWrite(event)=>{ console.log(event.data.val())`

Comment: Thanks, I've got `"firebase-functions": "^0.9.0"` in my dependencies. Should I change it to `"firebase-functions": "^1.0"`?

Comment: yes check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using the older version of firebase-function, that is why `params` and `change.after` are undefined, to update you need to go to the functions folder, and do the following:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@latest --save
```

Also update `firebase-tools`:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

then you will be able to use the new version, more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: I'm getting `npm WARN firebase-functions@1.0.1 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.12.0 but none is installed`. Any reason not to update to `firebase-admin@latest`?

Comment: it says "Important: SDK version 1.0.0 requires firebase-admin 5.11.0." so you need to update it also

Comment: Current version of `firebase-functions` is 1.0.1, which requires `firebase-admin` version 5.12.0

Comment: yes true firebase-admin was updated yesterday to 5.12.0. The sentence that I wrote in the comment was just from the documentation but do `npm install firebase-admin@5.12.0 --save` or `@latest`